# Proportional Pie-charts using High-Charts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am working with High Charts to plot two pi charts which I need to be proportional. I have calculated the radius of each, but can't find a way to specify a radius for each pi chart. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use pie series `size` property.

From docs:

> ## size: String|Number
>
> The diameter of the pie relative to the plot area. Can be a percentage or pixel value. Pixel values are given as integers. The default behaviour (as of 3.0) is to scale to the plot area and give room for data labels within the plot area. As a consequence, the size of the pie may vary when points are updated and data labels more around. In that case it is best to set a fixed value, for example "75%". Defaults to .

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2cncenc7/)